# mysql update table if column exists (foreach)

Tags: php, mysql

I've been playing with this :

```
foreach($textnode as $key => $value) {

$value = stripslashes($value);
 $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value, $con);

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO paragraphs (paragraphs, url)
 VALUES ('$value', '$url')");



}
```

I've been trying to update the column "paragraphs" for where the url already exists

This doesn't seem to work well as it just replaces each row in paragraphs with the 1st paragraph. (repeats it over and over again)

```
mysql_query("UPDATE paragraphs SET paragraphs = '$value'
 WHERE url = '$url'");
```

Comment: You have a column with the same name as the table? What does your DBA have to say about this?

Comment: nothing because Im just practicing.....

Comment: Are you against making a basic query against the database to see if a valid row exists and update if so?

Comment: I don't see any $url variable being instantiated?

Comment: no ...would that be fairly inefficient though?

Comment: I store the get the $url from another script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `url` field unique?

If not, add a UNIQUE constraint on it and use [**`INSERT INTO . . . ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) with something like this:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO paragraphs (paragraphs, url)
                VALUES ('$value', '$url')
              ON DUPLICATE KEY
                UPDATE paragraphs = '$value'
             ");
```

or (do you want to "append" the new `'$value'` when `url` already exists?):

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO paragraphs (paragraphs, url)
                VALUES ('$value', '$url')
              ON DUPLICATE KEY
                UPDATE paragraphs = CONCAT(paragraphs, '$value')
             ");
```

Comment: ya it is ...how would I do that using foreach though

Comment: @Pranet: No, I think there needs to exist a UNIQUE constraint for the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` to work. If `url` is the primary key, thats's fine too.

Comment: Would finding to see if the url exists and replacing each row with the url with the new values be possible...I think thats what I'm looking for

Comment: You can use `IF EXISTS ...` syntax but I think it needs you to create a stored procedure and it's not the best option for many other reasons. Look here anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168822/mysql-update-if-exists-else-insert-with-two-keys

Answer (score 0):

Try running the query

```
SELECT paragraphs, url
FROM   paragraphs;
```

to see what your table really contains. It may be that you've put in all the same URLs into your table. Which would explain the update behavior.