# IF NOT EXISTS INSERT OR UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert a row , if the row does not exists and if it exists, I want to update the row. I am currently using mysql 5.1.67

This is my MYSQL code :

```
IF EXISTS(select * from tabSingles where `doctype` = 'Control Panel' and `field` = 'time_zone') 
THEN
update tabSingles SET `value` = 'Asia/Calcutta' where `doctype` = 'Control Panel' and `field` = 'time_zone'
ELSE 
insert into tabSingles (`doctype`,`field`,`value`) VALUES ('Control Panel','time_zone','Asia/Calcutta')
```

But this always throws an error :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS(select * from tabSingles where `doctype` = 'Control Panel' AND `fi' at line 1
```

I know that I can use the "REPLACE" or "INSERT.... ON DUPLICATE KEY" to perform this operation but the problem is there is no PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY in this table, and the project that I am working on is an OPEN-SOURCE, so we cannot change the DATABASE SCHEMA. If we do that, then we will have to continue the process every time we get a new update from them.

So please can anyone help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tabSingles WHERE `doctype` LIKE 'Control Panel' AND `field` LIKE 'time_zone'); 
 BEGIN 
  UPDATE tabSingles SET `value` = 'Asia/Calcutta' WHERE `doctype` LIKE 'Control Panel' AND `field` LIKE 'time_zone' 
 END;
ELSE 
 BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO tabSingles (`doctype`,`field`,`value`) VALUES ('Control Panel','time_zone','Asia/Calcutta') 
 END IF;
```

OR

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [tabSingles] WHERE `doctype` LIKE 'Control Panel' AND `field` LIKE 'time_zone'); 
 BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO [tabSingles] (`doctype`,`field`,`value`) VALUES ('Control Panel','time_zone','Asia/Calcutta');
 END;
ELSE  
  BEGIN 
    UPDATE [tabSingles] SET `value` = 'Asia/Calcutta' WHERE `doctype` LIKE 'Control Panel' AND `field` LIKE 'time_zone'  
  END IF;
```

OR, Try it manully

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabSingles WHERE `doctype` LIKE 'Control Panel' AND `field` LIKE 'time_zone';");       
IF (mysql_affected_rows()==0) 
{
 $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabSingles (`doctype`,`field`,`value`) VALUES ('Control Panel','time_zone','Asia/Calcutta');");
}  
ELSE 
{
 $result = mysql_query("UPDATE tabSingles SET `value` = 'Asia/Calcutta' WHERE `doctype` LIKE 'Control Panel' AND `field` LIKE 'time_zone';"); 
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error :  IF EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM `tabSingles`
WHERE `doctype` LIKE 'Control Panel'
AND `field` LIKE 'time_zone'
);

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `tabSingles` WHERE `doctype` LIKE 'Control Panel' AND `f' at line 1

Comment: yes, i tried your answer, i got this error, i am confused right now, whether "IF EXISTS" is available in the MYSQL 5.1 or is it being removed or something else.

Comment: still the same error, if you have mysql on your localhost, would you please execute your mysql statements ?? as my server as well as localhost throws the same error.

Comment: i want to bring this into notice that, this above command will not be executed in a function or in a stored procedure.

Comment: I dont have local host at now, so try it manualy ..as updated in answer. it should work..

Comment: also check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6168844/2372960), its same as my answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

`Replace` works by first deleting the row (by the unique index) and then inserting a new one. You can do that manually if you like, just not by the unique index. If there is no row to delete then that is fine. This is as expensive as `replace`, just make sure you have a proper index for the delete and you'll be fine.

```
DELETE FROM tabsingles 
WHERE ` doctype ` = 'Control Panel' 
      AND ` field ` = 'time_zone'; 

INSERT INTO tabsingles 
            ( ` doctype ` , 
             ` field ` , 
             ` value ` ) 
VALUES      ('Control Panel', 
             'time_zone', 
             'Asia/Calcutta');
```